# Lubuntu LXQt 19.10 fonts

Tags: lubuntu, fonts, lxqt, mozilla

came here from debian XFCE and enjoyed Lubuntu LXQt very much: it's obviously faster, corrrectly installed drivers, works fluetntly. Just one problem remains: if I set system fonts, mozilla firefox and thunderbrid, zim notebook menu fonts comes out so tiny. Still cant figure how to correct this. Thank you for any hints!

Comment: I'll provide the following which I hope is helpful, firstly I'd look up the manual (eg. https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.2/3.2.2/appearance.html?highlight=fonts), a quick look at the firefox package (https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/firefox) shows me it's using GTK3 configs, so possibly may ignore the Qt setup used by your LXQt desktop (I'd expect the same for thunderbird being from mozilla as well, I don't know your others). I don't notice any difference in firefox on my box sorry.

Comment: @guiverc [zim](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/zim) seems to be gtk3-based as well.

Comment: So, if firefox looks for GTK3 configs, is it possible somehow to give this in Qt environment? Ive partially managed problem installing Qt5.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by *installing Qt5* as Lubuntu's LXQt uses Qt5 by default and the libraries are thus already installed. I haven't experienced your issue on any setup I use, nor QA/support testing (very vanilla) setups but I suspect the tiny fonts are an issue with HiDef screens I don't use/have. I just Ctrl+ to increase fonts for tab/windwos, if the default *Language and Appearance* settings firefox already provides wasn't enough (I use default (dejavu serif) size 16).

Comment: I've installded qt5ct, instructions given at https://www.pcsuggest.com/lxqt-dark-style/, now I'm able manage separately fonts for file manager, qt apps and panel. Then I can increase font size in LXQt appearance configuration and get bigger menu fonts for mozilla FF and TB. Down side is that i get huge fonts on some few apps. PS: Ctrl+ increases only content size, not menu. I use old Sony Vaio mashine with nvidia driver for GeForce GT 425M. Thank you very much for your help! I'm now somehow satisfied with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the appearance settings and increase the **system font size**.